Derivative of $\ln (\tan(x))$ using first principle
Find the definition derivative of $\ln (\tan(x))$. Using simple step.
Let $f(x)= \ln(\tan(x))$   and
$f(x+h) = \ln (\tan(x+h))$
Now,
By definition,
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln( \tan(x+h))-\ln( \tan(x)) }{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln \left(\frac{\tan(x+h)}{\tan(x)}\right)} {h}$$
From this I can't solve further.

If you were allowed to use that $~\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left{ ~\ln[ ~f(x) ~] ~\right} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)},~$ and were allowed to use that $~\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left[ ~\sin ~x ~\right] = \cos(x), ~\frac{d}{dx}\left[ ~\cos ~x ~\right] = -\sin(x),~$ and were allowed to use that $~\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left[ ~\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} ~\right] = \frac{g(x)f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{[ ~g(x) ~]^2},~$ then the problem would be greatly simplified. ...see next comment

In "Calculus" 2nd Edition, 1966, Vol 1 (Tom Apostol) a great deal of time is spent deriving the results in the previous comment, by starting with the basic definition of $~\displaystyle f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.~$  If I understand the posted question correctly, you are asking for a MathSE reviewer to follow in the same footsteps as Apostol's "Calculus" textbook, or (presumably) any corresponding real analysis textbook.  I imagine the (formal) derivations would be lengthy.  This is why there are math textbooks.

This question is not about differential equations. Please, tag the question carefully.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: use the results$$\begin{align}\ln\tan(x+h)-\ln\tan x&=\ln(1+\tan h\cot x)-\ln(1-\tan h\tan x),\\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\tan h}{h}&=1.\end{align}$$

Write $\tan(x+h) /\tan x$ as $1+\frac{\tan(x+h)-\tan x} {\tan x} =1+A$ so that $A\to 0$ and divide multiply your expression by $A $ to get $\frac{\log(1+A)}{A}\cdot\frac{A}{h}$.

By first principle of derivatives we get $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$
Then as you have rightly written $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\tan(x+h)}{\tan(x)}\right)}{h}.$...(1)
Now we can expand $tan(x+h) $ using its first-order approximation as
$\tan(x+h) \approx \tan(x) + h \sec^2(x)$ as $ h\to 0$ .
Now substituting this we get
$\frac{\tan(x+h)}{\tan(x)} \approx \frac{\tan(x) + h \sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)} = 1 + \frac{h \sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)}.$...(2)
Substituting (2) in (1) we get $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{h \sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)})}{h}$
For small $u$ we get $\ln(1+u)  \approx  u$, therefore $\ln\left(1 + \frac{h \sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)}\right) \approx \frac{h \sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)}.$
Therefore $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{h \sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)}}{h}.$
This gives $f'(x)=\frac{\sec^2(x)}{\tan(x)}$
Which implies $f'(x) =\frac{1}{\sin(x) \cos(x)}=\csc(x) \sec(x).$
